# Inverse fft does not give back the same image

Tags: image-processing, fft, matlab, fourier-transform

I tried to Fourier decompose my image using FFT and reconstruct it back using IFFT. While I did this, I noticed something peculiar:

[image]

The first image is the regular one, and the second is the image I constructed by re-combining the DFT:

```
[g, map]=imread("skull.png");

gdft=fft2(g);
f=ifft2(gdft);

subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(g,map)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(f)
```

As you can see, I applied the function and the inverse successively which means there should technically be no change in the image. Why is there such a noticeable change then? I think there is a loss of information on the relative magnitudes of gray values to some extent.

Maybe relevant details:

- The program was written in Matlab
- The image is 16x16 grayscale in nature

Comment: `imshow` does something different for integer (your g) and floating-point (your f) images. Use `imshow(f,[0,255])`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that completely blackened the image

Comment: Oh, `g` is an index into the color map... you should do `g = ind2rgb(g,map);` before processing it. This will likely give you an RGB image rather than a gray-scale image, so then do `g = rgb2gray(g);`. You can now display `imshow(g)`, and compute `f=ifft2(fft2(g))`, and see that `f-g` is small everywhere.

Comment: @CrisLuengo somehow that did end up working! Why exactly do we have to go back and forth between rgb and grayscale? I remember doing some image processing in Julia and it was very straightforward.

Comment: @DatBoi, Could you share the image?

Comment: @Royi https://pixeljoint.com/files/icons/full/skull__r1330156201.png

Comment: @DatBoi You don't "have to go back and forth". You read in an indexed image as a separate index array and color map. You don't need to do that, you could read it as `g=imread(...)` and get the RGB image directly. Even though it's a grayscale image, it's saved as an RGB image to file. You could also save it as a grayscale image, then you wouldn't need to convert from RGB to grayscale. And of course you could apply the FFT to the RGB image, but it's just typically easier to learn about the FFT if the input is grayscale.

Comment: @DatBoi, I updated my answer to handle the case of indexed image and `uint8` image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `imread()` on the image, the output is array of `uint8`.
When you apply the `fft2()` it converts it to `double` hence also the output of `ifft2()` is `double`.

When you plot using `imshow()` image of class `double` it uses `[0, 1]` range while the data is in the range `[0, 255]`.

The other issue is having an image with mapped colors.

##### Handle Indexed / Mapped Image

Credit to @[CrisLuengo](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/33605/cris-luengo) who spotted this.

```matlab
[mI, mG] = imread('https://i.imgur.com/FhCgvnX.png');
mI = ind2rgb(mI, mG); %<! Scales into [0, 1]

mII = ifft2(fft2(mI), 'symmetric');

figure();
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(mI);
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(mII);
```

##### Handle General RGB Image

I saved the RGB image (Output of `ind2rgb(mI, mG)`) as a PNG then this will work:

```matlab
mI = imread('https://i.imgur.com/HhtNo4L.png'); %<! UINT8

mII = ifft2(fft2(mI), 'symmetric'); %<! Double in the range [0, 255]

figure();
subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(mI);
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(mII, [0, 255]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then obviously the function doesnt use the identity kernel for the convolution.You can write your own code to do the convolution by using the identity kernel.

Comment: Can you elaborate?